# Why ListInterpolation does not allow InterpolationOrder greater than 2 in the "y" direction?

Tags: interpolation

The order is always reduced to 2 in the "y" direction; I would want a better approximation to my data. Independent of the method (spline or hermite), I can choose any order for the "x" direction, but not for the "y" direction...

```
list= {{4.505, 39.2076, 42}, {11.0164, 33.1725, 33}, {14.9458, 
    24.7109, 44}, {2.2373, 22.7182, 13}, {20.9699, 41.815, 33}, {25.6,
     30.9317, 34}, {21.7007, 19.9014, 42}, {6.4073, 13.5153, 
    18}, {21.5101, 12.6544, 30}, {23.2593, 4.5582, 14}};

f= ListInterpolation[list, {{0, 36}, {0, 50}}, 
  Method -> "Hermite", InterpolationOrder -> 6]
Show[
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 36}, {y, 0, 50}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic],
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.05], 
    Table[Point[{list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]],
       list[[i, 3]]}], {i, 1, 10}]}], PlotRange -> {0, 50}]
```

[image]